# HTML Email renders larger in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

Outlook (2013) seems to be display my HTML emails substantially larger than any other client.

Relatively speaking, everything appears to be the correct proportions. But when compared to the email rendered in any browser or other client, the Outlook one looks HUGE.

Is anyone else getting this? Is it just my Outlook settings somehow or is there something I should have in my HTML to compensate?

[image]

Outlook on the left, Chrome GMail on the right, cut from the same screenshot.

The markup is nothing special:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-layout-alt:fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="display:block!important;max-width:520px!important;margin:0 auto!important;padding:0 10px 40px;" style="width:520px;padding:0 10px 40px;">
            <div style="max-width:520px;margin:0 auto;display:block;width:auto;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p style="font:700 20px/28px Arial;margin:22px 0 0;padding:0;color:#000000;">This is an H1 element</p>
                            <p style="font:100 15px/23px Arial;margin:16px 0 0;padding:0;color:#4d4e53;">This is a paragraph element with text about us and how we should put a period in here somewhere, but I'm a developer not a content writer so that's on you. The color of the paragraphs is #4d4e53 while the Header (H1-H4) are black.</p>
                            <p style="font:700 18px/26px Arial;margin:16px 0 0;padding:0;color:#000000;">This is an H2 element</p>
                            <p style="font:100 15px/23px Arial;margin:16px 0 0;padding:0;color:#4d4e53;">This is another paragraph element. This is a <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#59BCE9;">link to somewhere</a> and <span style="white-space:nowrap;">614-123-4567</span> is how a phone number is formatted.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your markup. Note - all CSS has to be inlined to work on Outlook. I use Zurbs inliner. Seems to work quite well for cross client consistency in HTML email.

http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html

Comment: @Korgrue There's nothing special. All of my styles are inline, in px, and I'm using table structure. Absolutely everything is correct as far as layout, relative spacing, etc.. It simply displays larger in Outlook.

Comment: Did you make sure your zoom level is set to default in the client?
To reset zoom level in Outlook 2013:

    Open a new message.
    Click the Zoom button on the ribbon.
    Change the zoom to the desired level.
    Close the message.
    Click new message (or reply) and the zoom should be the desired level.

Comment: @Korgrue Outlook zoom is at 100% (first thing I checked). Appears to be about the same size as browser renders if I zoom out to 70-80%

Comment: Give this a read: https://litmus.com/community/discussions/151-mystery-solved-dpi-scaling-in-outlook-2007-2013

Seems that using PX as your value for Outlook might be the problem. Outlook 2013 converts PX to PT using Words rendering engine, and then applies any client properties the new value. You need to use VML to force proper sizing in Outlook.

Comment: @Korgrue Ah okay that actually explains it. This is a company machine, went and changed the settings (to 100% display) and now it matches the other renders. I'm not going to modify my particular code as it is lining up just fine regardless, but this is good to know!

Comment: Fantastic! Glad you were able to sort it out. HTML emails are not the easiest thing to mark up...

Answer (score 0):

With high resolution screens Outlook zoom level can automatically be set to 120 dpi. Glad to know everything is rendering in correct proportions, but in case they don't, here is a solution you can use,

https://litmus.com/community/discussions/151-mystery-solved-dpi-scaling-in-outlook-2007-2013

Basically you add the vml code at the top and set width and height of elements inside style tags.